# Probability that a face comes up less than $m$ times for $n$ dice throws

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's say I have a 6 face dice and I throw it `n` times, what is the probability that one face comes up less than `m` times in total? For instance what is the probability that the face 3 comes less than 5 times in 200 throws?

I know the probability of a face coming less than one time in `n` throws is `(1-(1/6))^n` but I don't know how to generalize it for when I want to know the probability for less than `m` times.

Thank you.

Comment: See [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), specifically $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)}.$

Answer (score 1):

Let p= probabilty of success. Q = probabilty of failure , and p+q=1.

Therefore , $$(q+p)^n = \sum_{r=0}^{n} {n \choose r}{q^{n-r}}{p^r}$$ ...(1)

Now , coefficient of , say $p^r$ in the expansion of (1),is equal to the probabilty of $'r' $
successs when the experiment is done $'n'$ times .

Now ,in your case , p = getting that required face = ${1 \over 6}$
,And q = Not getting that face = ${5 \over 6}$.
Therefore ,probabilty of getting that required face less than 'm' times =  sum of terms with $p^0 , p^1 , \ldots , p^{m-1} $ in expansion (1)  , which is equal to
$$\sum_{r=0}^{m-1} {n \choose r} {q^{n-r}} { p^r} $$ ,
Where ${p = {1 \over 6}}, {q = {5 \over 6}}$